# str or byte confusion when reading json data in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm reading a file with a chat export from Facebook in python with the following example:

```
jsonMessages = []

with open("Facebook/message_1.json", 'rb') as file1:
    json1 = json.load(file1)
    jsonMessages.extend(json1['messages'])

jsonMessages[0]['content']

for msg in jsonMessages:
    print(msg)
```

My first print attempt, where i just print the content of the message in position 0 outputs the content of the message as expected.

But when i iterate the list and try the same, i get the error message below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[170], line 10
  7 jsonMessages[0]['content']
  9 for msg in jsonMessages:
---> 10     print(msg)

File <frozen codecs>:378, in write(self, object)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py:622, in OutStream.write(self, string)
620 if not isinstance(string, str):
621     msg = f"write() argument must be str, not {type(string)}"
--> 622     raise TypeError(msg)
624 if self.echo is not None:
625     try:

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not <class 'bytes'>
```

The worst is, if i treat the message as byte and try to `decode()` it, i get the error that says it's a dict!

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Open with 'r' not 'rb' to get str input rather than bytes.

Comment: this seems to be some issue with IPython. The code you provided wouldn't throw that error by itself. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Malcolm that won't make any difference, those bytes are decoded into some pyhton data structure, `json.load` handles files in text or binary mode

Comment: So, if you run this code normally, e.g put it in some `.py` file then `python foo.py` it won't give you this error